# Java get int numbers from DateFormat and have user Input

Tags: java

In my code I want to have the individual numbers from date format so I can use them as int values:

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy";

public int age()
{
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    Date date = new Date();

// How to convert to int?
        int currentnDay = ?;
        int currentMonth = ?;
        int currentYear = ?;
}
```

also I would like some user input to define day,month and year in one go, if that's even possible:

```
private Date dateOfPublication;

public void input() 
{
    Scanner scn = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.print( "Please enter dateOfPublication: " );
// How to setup input for this?
}
```

I hope you can help me out, previously I did it all seperatly but the code was quite big and I think it would be prettier if I could do it like that..

update: okay I'm doing the input like this now:

```
    System.out.print( "Please enter dateOfPublication, use format of x.x.xxxx: " );
    userInputDate = scn.next();

    String[] ary = userInputDate.split("\\.");

    publicationDay = Integer.parseInt(ary[0]);
    publicationMonth = Integer.parseInt(ary[1]);
    publicationYear = Integer.parseInt(ary[2]);
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
dateFormat.format(today).split("\\.");
```

For your code:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
Date date = new Date();

String[] dateArr = dateFormat.format(today).split("\\.");

int currentnDay = Integer.parseInt(dateArr[0]);
int currentMonth = Integer.parseInt(dateArr[1]);
int currentYear = Integer.parseInt(dateArr[2]);
```

**[IdeOne Example](https://ideone.com/roROBq)**

Comment: Anything wrong with `Calendar#get` and using `Calendar.DATE`, `Calendar.MONTH` and ``Calendar.YEAR` (if you're not using Java 8 or JodaTime)?

Comment: Cool, and what about the user input? should I just try what MadProgrammer suggests?

Comment: @MadProgrammer nope, I like that but I've just continued  OP code.

Comment: @DisasterCoder I'm not clear what you want, if you want the user to set the same string by input then it's the same

Comment: @FedericoPiazza Fair enough, I'd just freak if I had team member do this in production ;)

Comment: Well its simple. I want the user to give an input according to the Date_Format and fill in the (private Date dateOfPublication;) variable, after that I want to again get the day, month and year seperatly so I can make further calculations..?

Comment: @DisasterCoder glad to help. Thanks for the tick

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Java 8's new Time API (or JodaTime or `Calendar` if you're really stuck)

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse("16.10.2015", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT));
System.out.println(ld);
System.out.println(ld.getDayOfMonth());
System.out.println(ld.getMonth().getValue()); 
System.out.println(ld.getYear());
```

Which outputs

```
2015-10-16
16
10
2015
```

Now, you could simply ask the user to input a date in a given format and try and parse the result, if the parsing fails, you could reprompt them

For example...

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
LocalDate ld = null;
do {

    System.out.print("Please enter date in " + DATE_FORMAT + " format: ");
    String value = input.nextLine();

    try {
        ld = LocalDate.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(value + " is not a valid date for the format of " + DATE_FORMAT);
    }

} while (ld == null);

System.out.println(ld);
System.out.println(ld.getDayOfMonth());
System.out.println(ld.getMonth().getValue()); // Is probably 0 indexed
System.out.println(ld.getYear());
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to parse the input string
The Calendar data type is more flexible for date-time handling. This is an example that shows some Date/Calendar operations.

```
Date date;
Calendar c;
// Get the current date
c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Current Calendar:" + c.getTime().toString());
    
int currentnDay = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
int currentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int currentYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
System.out.println(String.format("Current Values: %d/%d/%d",
                                            currentnDay, currentMonth, currentYear));
    
String DATE_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
date = dateFormat.parse("11.10.1981");
System.out.println("Modified Date:" + date.toString());

// reset Calendar
c = Calendar.getInstance();
// set date to the calendar 
c.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());

currentnDay = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
currentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
currentYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
System.out.println(String.format("Modified Values: %d/%d/%d",
                                            currentnDay, currentMonth, currentYear));
```

This is the output of the example.

> Current Calendar:Thu Oct 15 20:22:59 EDT 2015
>
> Current Values: 15/9/2015
>
> Modified Date:Sun Oct 11 00:00:00 EDT 1981
>
> Modified Values: 11/9/1981